# PowerPoint 2010 Open New Presentation Dialog from VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I need to simulate the action File > New > My Templates (from the Available Templates and Themes) via a VBA macro / code.

This presents the "New Presentation" dialog.

There is no macro recorder in PowerPoint 2010.

Comment: Why was this question voted down?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. I think all you can do is use code to open the standard file dialog e.g.

```
Application.FileDialog(ppFileDialogOpen).show
```